# Add new row as Total Grade in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a list of a student's transcript in the last row (total score) as the total grade point average

For example:

| Course | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Math | 15 |
| Physics | 19 |
| Chemistry | 14 |
| Total Average | 16 |

But I can't make the last row (Total Average)
Is there a way to create a virtual row?

```sql
select crs.Name,
Grade,
crs.CourseTypeId
from Student std
    inner join Selection sct on sct.StudentId = std.Id
    inner join Major mjr on mjr.Id = std.MajorId
    inner join CourseMajor CrsM on CrsM.MajorId = mjr.Id
    inner join Course crs on crs.Id = Crsh.CourseId
    inner join Teach tch on tch.CourseId = crs.Id
    inner join Teacher tchr on tchr.Id = tch.TeacherId
    inner join Unit unt on unt.TeachId = tchr.Id
    inner join Term trm on trm.Id = unt.TermId
where std.FirstName = N'sara' 
    and TermId = EnterTermId
order by crs.Name
```

Comment: Looking into `ROLLUP` and/or `GROUPING SETS`

Comment: Normally you do that in your front end.

Comment: @DaleK I know, but this is my scenario

Comment: @Larnu I tried to do this but this work with sum ,not avg

Comment: @Larnu I may have made a mistake!

Comment: How do you calculate your grade point average?

Comment: @DaleK (Sum of course scores /number of lessons) or (avg() )  .I think this question will be resolved through the Union

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can just use:

```
(select(SUM(50/5))) as 'AVG1'
(select(AVG(50/5))) as 'AVG2'
```

as a new column,

```
select tbl_Test.id2, tbl_Test.sName
    , (select(SUM(50/5))) as 'AVG'
from tbl_Test;
```

**Update:**
Create a new table and set the calculation and the name, mine I created **tbl_result** to store **result** as caption and **totalAverage** as a decimal to store the calculation AVG, SUM, etc.
The best way to implement this is by using **Stored Procedure** here you can create a virtual table as you say that.

```
select * from tbl_result;
-- Insert your cal. here
insert into tbl_result (idr, result, totalAverage ) values (1, 'Total Average', (select(AVG(50/5))))

-- Get the result and combine with your select as 'Virtual row' :)
select tbl_Test.id2, tbl_Test.sName from tbl_Test
union
select tbl_result.totalAverage, tbl_result.result from tbl_result
```

The final result:
[image: Result]

Here is how you can do it using Stored Procedure SP:

```
USE [Testing]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Result]    Script Date: 3/19/2022 10:46:18 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Result]

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tempTable AS TABLE (rid INT, result nvarchar(50), totalAverage decimal(18,4))
    DECLARE @cal as decimal(18,4)

    -- Get your cal. avg, sum, count ....
    select @cal = AVG(tbl_Test.id2) from tbl_Test
    -- save the result....
    insert into @tempTable (rid, result, totalAverage) values (1, 'Total Average', @cal)

    -- Return the final result: 
    select tbl_Test.id2, tbl_Test.sName from tbl_Test
    union
    select totalAverage, result from @tempTable


END
```

**How to run SP?**
-- Execute the SP
exec sp_Result

Comment: I want a virtual row, not a column

Comment: I just give you an example of you doing it, but I will update the answer. @mehrbanooEbrahimzade